# Ada2012 & GNAT: compile library under a namespace

Tags: ada, gnat

Can I compile a library adding a namespace at compile time using GNAT?
I have to link to a legacy library that don't use a root package and child packages, so it's very annoying having hundred of options when I have to include something.

The other option I have is to write a Python script to add the root package to all files to reduce the problem.

Comment: What/where are those "hundreds of options" you talk about? On the compiler command line, in your project file, or in your Ada source? How would they be reduced by having a root package? If you are talking about "with" clauses in your Ada source, having a root package for the library will not help, you still have to "with" any child package your code needs access to. However, if you only need a subset of the library functionality, you could write a wrapper package that exports only that functionality, and internally uses and "withs" whatever library packages it actually needs.

Comment: Just a pedantic quibble: Ada uses packages and not namespaces. Namespaces are a C++ nomenclature and C++ namespaces are not equivalent to Ada packages.

Comment: @NiklasHolsti I mean in my Ada source. The library I have to link has not been developped using child packages, so when I try to 'with' something, hundred of options are suggested because the library has hundred of packages. I was wondering if there exists a compiler option to add a common name to those Ada packages at compile time

Comment: @JimRogers I know I know, what I meant with namespace was not the C++ namespace. But as I understood, an Ada package provides a namespace for its contents. Thank you :)

Comment: It sounds like your legacy software was created with nested packages, much like the standard Ada.Text_IO package. A package provides a scope for its contents, not a namespace. Hierarchical packages do not extend a namespace, they create a new scope with well defined visibility into the parent package and without modifying the parent package. The comment by Niklas Holsti can simplify your context clauses throughout the bulk of your program.

Comment: So when you type "with Lib." in your IDE, the IDE suggests hundreds of continuations such as "with Lib.Foo", "with Lib.Bar" and so on. Are you sure that the suggestions are really packages, or might they include all identifiers declared in the Lib package? Have you studied the library to find out which of its services you need? That should show you which library packages you need, and you only have to "with" those packages. Even if those library packages "with" other library packages, you do not have to "with" those other library packages - they will come automatically.

Comment: Rereading your posting and comments, perhaps you are only annoyed at the long list of continuations that your IDE throws up, but you already knew that you don't have to "with" them all. You can surely disable this auto-completion function in your IDE. In addition to my earlier suggestion of a "wrapper" package, you could also use renaming packages, "package LibFoo renames Lib.Foo", and then write "with LibFoo". Or "package Wrap is package Foo renames Lib.Foo; package Bar renames Lib.Bar; ... end Wrap".

Comment: @NiklasHolsti the problem is that the library packages aren't under "Lib" root package, they are 'floating' packages, so anytime I have to include something it's a hell to find anything.